# Alterar uma TextBox para Multiline mantendo os CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox

Tenho uma aplicação web com diversas TextBoxes.
No entanto, preciso que algumas delas fiquem com Multiline devido ao texto que vão conter.
Cada vez que faço essa alteração perco as configurações de CSS.
Pelo que pesquisei parece-me que a TextBox se transforma em TextArea em Runtime.

Assim, precisava saber como manter ou até adicionar CSS a esse objecto, de forma a manter as minhas back colours, fontes e Tamanhos.

Exemplo de ASP:

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCC"  runat="server" TextMode = "MultiLine"  Width="100%" CssClass="textArea" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Exemplo de CSS

```
 .textArea 
{ 
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Pode nos fornecer o código que tu já criou para isso?

Comment: Editado para incluir código

Comment: faz mais uma coisa? dê uma olhada no html que é gerado na página com o multiline e sem o multiline, teoricamente se tu setou uma classe para o textbox ele deveria utilizar dela...

Comment: Ao ver o codigo gerado, ele coloca a textbox como textarea mas ignora o CSS, dai a minha questao....

Answer (score 2):

Criando uma aplicação simples, com os dados informados na questão, pode-se ver que o CSS é aplicado mesmo utilizando-se `TextMode="MultiLine". Logo, provavelmente a página não está encontrando o arquivo de CSS. Veja o exemplo a seguir, que mostra a página Default.aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .textArea
        {
            background-color: green;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 21px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 3000px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCC" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" CssClass="textArea"
        ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Veja que coloquei uma cor de background verde, para ficar evidente que a aplicação do CSS funciona. Também mudei o tamanho da fonte para novamente evidenciar a alteração de estilo.